# Is it possible to modify server response on client side?

Tags: javascript, json, security, frontend, backend

Lets say I have this frontend application that performs a login.
Upon username/password sent to server, backend will make some operations to understand if the user (for example) has payed for using the service.
So backend will send a response that could look like this:

```
{
message: "ok"
user: {
  firstName: "John"
  ,lastName: "Doe"
  ,hasPayedForSubscription: false
}
}
```

Based on this response, the frontend will decide if it should show protected content that is accessible only for subscribed users.
Is this safe enough? Or there is a way for somebody to change the value of "hasPayedForSubscription" to "true" in order to access content for subscribed users?

Comment: protected content should also come from server

Comment: Definitely possible to modify the response. All you'd have to do is open dev console and monkey patch fetch or XHR to insert your own custom code in the process. I've done that before to "scrape" API calls